How to get an "average" for a categorical variable?
I have a large dataset that has 12 quadrats per survey with a slew of data. Most is numeric, but I have one categorical variable (Grazing - Either "Present" or "Absent"), that I wish to utilize. I've created a single row of data per survey by averaging the numeric variables in the 12 quadrats to have one average value for each survey rather than 12, however I'm not sure how to have that carry over with my categorical variable.
As Grazing is either Present or Absent, it is rather simple conceptually. If any of the 12 quadrats in each survey has Grazing presence, Grazing should be present on the survey. If not, it should be absent.
Example data:
CL.SGN.Data.Sample <- structure(list(Species = c("Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", 
"Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", 
"Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. japonica", 
"Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", 
"Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", 
"Z. japonica", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", 
"Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", 
"Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. marina", "Z. japonica", "Z. japonica", 
"Z. japonica", "Z. japonica"), Survey_Date = structure(c(1350518400, 
1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 
1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 
1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 
1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1350518400, 1357689600, 
1357689600, 1357689600, 1357689600, 1357689600, 1357689600, 1357689600, 
1357689600, 1357689600, 1357689600, 1357689600, 1357689600, 1357689600, 
1357689600, 1357689600, 1357689600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Year = c("2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013"), Quarter = c("4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), Site_Name = c("Birch Bay", 
"Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", 
"Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", 
"Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", 
"Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", 
"Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", 
"Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", 
"Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", 
"Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay", "Birch Bay"), Quad = c("Q1", 
"Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", 
"Q12", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", 
"Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", 
"Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"), Cover = c(0.75, 
0.75, 0.45, 0.65, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 
0, 0, 0.05, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.75, 0.65, 0.3, 0.75, 
0.15, 0.15, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.05, 0, 0, 0.05, 0), Calculated_Density = c(65, 
60, 26, 20, 3.75, 9, 9, 16, 8, 5, 5, 2, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 7.75, 3.75, 9.25, 1.5, 1, 2.5, 0.75, 6, 0.25, 
1, 4, 0, 0, NA, 0), Average_Height = c(46.6666666666667, 39.9, 
42, 53.5, 41.6666666666667, 40, 48.8333333333333, 54.6666666666667, 
66, 30.5, 47.5, 50, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 
29.8333333333333, 23.2333333333333, 30, 34.1666666666667, 37.3333333333333, 
39.5, 33.1666666666667, 43.6666666666667, 33.6666666666667, 45.8333333333333, 
28.1666666666667, 0, 0, NA, 0), Grazing = c("Absent", "Absent", 
"Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", 
"Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", NA, NA, "Absent", 
"Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", 
"Present", "Present", "Absent", "Present", "Present", "Absent", 
"Present", "Present", "Absent", "Present", "Absent", "Absent", 
"Absent", "Absent", NA, "Absent"), Year.Quarter = structure(c(2012.75, 
2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 
2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 
2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 2012.75, 
2012.75, 2012.75, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013), class = "yearqtr")), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

CL.SGN.Data.Sample

Example Code arriving at mean values. (Note in my actual code, Density, Height and Cover are separated to reduce data loss due to NA removal).
SGN.ZM.Survey_Means <- CL.SGN.DATA %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Species, "Z. marina")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Calculated_Density),
         !is.na(Average_Height),
         !is.na(Cover)) %>%
  summarize(across(c(Cover, Average_Height, Calculated_Density), mean), .by = c(Site_Name, Survey_Date))
SGN.ZM.Survey_Means


This is a case where if I knew what to search for I could find the answer, but in every search results have not been helpful.
I thought about adding Grazing into the summary like so, but obviously it produces NA's as you can't take a mean of categorical data...
SGN.ZM.Survey_Means <- CL.SGN.DATA %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Species, "Z. marina")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Calculated_Density),
         !is.na(Average_Height),
         !is.na(Cover)) %>%
  summarize(across(c(Cover, Average_Height, Calculated_Density, Grazing), mean), .by = c(Site_Name, Survey_Date))
SGN.ZM.Survey_Means


Thanks for adding in your sample data, but there are no instances where Grazing == "Present" - so it makes providing assistance a little difficult. Could you edit your question to include such data, and your desired output?

You could try something like CL.SGN.Data.Sample %>% mutate(grazing_any = +any(Grazing == "Present"), .by = Quad) to place a 1 for any Quad with a "Present" value, then in your summarize, use max(grazing_any)

@jpsmith I've updated my sample data.
For your suggestion, how would I implement that second condition into summarize? It does not appear to be working any way I try:
SGN.ZM.Survey_Means <- CL.SGN.DATA %>%
filter(str_detect(Species, "Z. marina")) %>%
filter(!is.na(Calculated_Density),
!is.na(Average_Height),
!is.na(Cover)) %>%
summarize(across(c(Cover, Average_Height, Calculated_Density), mean), max(Grazing),  .by = c(Site_Name, Survey_Date))

Thanks Shanafelt_Ben, but it's still unclear what you would want your final data to look like. Could you edit your question to include the desired output from the example data? This may require just manually plugging in what you would expect to see.

If I've read your question correctly, what if you made your character variable as a factor? then you can do frequency counts etc?

Would it be an option to express the ratios? Like aggregate(Grazing~Site_Name+Survey_Date, CL.SGN.Data.Sample, \(x) table(x) / length(x))?

So, for a given survey I have 12 rows of data. Each of those 12 rows (Quadrats) have their own set of recorded data. Most variables are numeric (Percent cover, counts & height.) However, one variable I care about is either present or absent, or as I have it now "1" = Present, "0" = Absent.
I've received mean values for the 12 quadrats making each survey have one row of data rather than 12 via means of the numeric data.
I want to have the highest value of those 12 quads represented per survey. So if any presence is detected the selected value is 1, if all 12 are absent the value is 0.

Most of the variables are numeric, so I calculated their averages across the quadrats.
For the Grazing column, goal is to mark it as "Present" for the survey if any of the 12 quadrats showed grazing presence; otherwise, it should be "Absent". Here’s the approach :
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

SGN.ZM.Survey_Means <- CL.SGN.Data.Sample %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Species, "Z. marina")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Calculated_Density), !is.na(Average_Height), !is.na(Cover)) %>%
  group_by(Site_Name, Survey_Date) %>%
  summarize(
    Cover = mean(Cover, na.rm = TRUE),
    Average_Height = mean(Average_Height, na.rm = TRUE),
    Calculated_Density = mean(Calculated_Density, na.rm = TRUE),
    Grazing = if_else(any(Grazing == "Present", na.rm = TRUE), "Present", "Absent"),
    .groups = "drop"
  )

This code filters for Z. marina species and removes rows with NA in any of the numeric columns. Then, within each Site_Name and Survey_Date group, it calculates the average for the numeric variables (Cover, Average_Height, and Calculated_Density). For Grazing, it uses if_else() to check if "Present" appears in any quadrat for that survey and sets the result accordingly.
Also the output is:
A tibble: 2 × 6
  Site_Name Survey_Date Cover   Average_Height Calculated_Density Grazing
  <chr>     <date>      <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>              <chr>  
1 Birch Bay 2012-10-18  0.249167 46.77000       19.06250           Absent 
2 Birch Bay 2013-01-09  0.295833 33.38083       3.895833           Present
This gives the single-row-per-survey summary, with "Present" or "Absent" in the Grazing column based on the presence of grazing in any quadrat. 

